# Passing a custom JWT to a RelyingParty custom profile in Azure AD B2C

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

The use case is a C# flow outside of B2C that requires some custom B2C policies.

There will be some SelfAsserted technical profiles that display screens to the user and I want to pass some InputClaims into a custom RelyingParty that calls these profiles via a UserJourney.

The way to do this seems to be via a custom JWT that contains the claims that are then mapped to the InputClaims in the RelyingParty.

Are there any code examples that show how to pass the JWT to the policy and XML examples that show how a RelyingParty consumes a custom JWT?

Note that this is a custom JWT not one derived via authentication.

Is there a way to validate the JWT that the policy receives?

Comment: Does [this previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48574721/7378174) help you out?

Comment: Yeah - thanks - so does B2C by default check the JWT signature? Otherwise anyone could mint a JWT and use that.

Comment: Yes, it validates the JWT signature, using the shared secret.